# Comparison Between 2 FIles and Printing the Result in a Desired For at using AWK

Tags: bash, shell, awk, compare

My files are as below:

**File 1:**

```
COL1|COL2|COL3|COL4|COL5

'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:13'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L5S'|'5042449536906016501541'

'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:20'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L6I'|'5042449603146028701550'

'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:23'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L6I'|'5042449603146028701555'
```

**File 2:**

```
COL1|COL2|COL3|COL4|COL5

'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:13'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L5Q'|'5042449536906016501541'

'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:20'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L6I'|'5042449603146028701550'

'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:20'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L6I'|'5042449603146028701555'
```

Here Primary Key is my 5th Column say it is stored always in a Variable `$var`

**The output I want in as follows:**

```
PrimaryKey|Column|File1Value|File2Value

'5042449536906016501541'|COL4|'1A3LA7015L5S'|'1A3LA7015L5Q'
'5042449603146028701555'|COL2|'2017-09-01 00:19:23'|'2017-09-01 00:19:20'
```

**I have tried using the following code:**

```
paste -d '|' File1 File2 | awk -F '|' -v col="pk1" \
    '{c=NF/2;for(i=1;i<=c;i++)if($i!=$(i+c))printf "%s|%s|%s|%s \n",$(i+$col+1),$i,$(i+c),$i-$(i+c)}'
```

However, this is not working as expected.

Comment: Have you attempted to solve it yourself?

Comment: Tried with the Below Snippet ->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> paste -d '|' File1 File2 | awk -F '|' -v col="pk1" '{c=NF/2;for(i=1;i<=c;i++)if($i!=$(i+c))printf "%s|%s|%s|%s \n",$(i+$col+1),$i,$(i+c),$i-$(i+c)}' .  But not working as expected

Comment: Also not sure how to include the column from the First row..

Comment: Pls include yr snippet in the question.

Answer (score 1):

A script like this using GNU AWK might work:

**script.awk**

```
BEGIN     { # setup file separator and sorting:
            FS=OFS="|" 
            PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
          }

# skip header lines
FNR == 1  { next }

# store first file
(FNR==NR) { f1[$5]=$0
            # skip processing of other rules and 
            # read the next line from input
            next
          }

# store second file
          { f2[$5]=$0
            if( ! ($5 in f1)) {
                f1[$5] = ""
            }
          }

# compare and print stored information
END       { print"PrimaryKey", "Column", "File1Value", "File2Value" 
            for( k in f1) {
                split( f1[k], arr1, "|")
                split( f2[k], arr2, "|")
                for( c = 1; c <= length( f1[ k ] ); c++ ) {
                    if( arr1[c] != arr2[c] ) {
                        print k, "COL" c, arr1[c], arr2[c] 
                    }
                }
            }
          }
```

You would run a command like this: `awk -f script.awk yourfile1 yourfile2`

Comment: The awk should perform column to column comparison between the 2Files and should print the result as I have given..  It should look for all columns and print differences if any like the format mentioned

Comment: @SamratSaha Ok I changed the script to meet your requirements.

Comment: And what if I have the numbers of columns in both files dynamic,?  I mean for example  suppose I have the number of columns in a variable  called $var which can have values like 4 or 5 etc etc..  How the code will change if I want to include $var as number of columns in file1 and file 2?

Comment: @SamratSaha You would need to specify the exact requirements and then either change the code here or hire a coder to do it for you :).   
Did you test the code with your `dynamic` number of columns? I would say as long as both files have the same number of columns and each comparable line has the same number of columns it should work, since I did not use the number of columns anywhere in my answer. (In a certain sense `length( f1[k])` should adopt to your `dynamic length`.)

Comment: Fisher - Thanks man its working as expected!

Comment: @ Lars Fischer - in the script above i see you are printing the column names by concatenating col and the position inside the script as . --- if( arr1[c] != arr2[c] ) {
                        print k, "COL" c, arr1[c], arr2[c]    , but actually it should be the column names ideally. What if suppose i have the column names in a file say columns.csv in the following format as below- cat columns.csv 
COL1|COL2|COL3|COL4|COL5
How this can be incorporated in the above script can you suggest plzz?

Comment: @SamratSaha You could e.g. map the names to index with a "map" : Iterate over the fields of columns.csv and store `map[i] = $i` (or vice versa), then use `map` according to your requirements. You might want to look up the awk documantation and read about "Arrays".